# gprof's output gmon.out not appearing when cancelling slurm job before its finish

Tags: performance, fortran, profiling, slurm, gprof

I am profiling a Fortran code with `gprof`.
I run this code on a cluster, where I request 24 cores from 1 node.

The job is submitted via `slurm`.
The command to run the code, inside the `submission.sh` I send via `sbatch submission.sh` is `srun`.

My question is why if I `scancel` the job after 10 minutes (say), i.e. without the job to exit normally (i.e. without the job to finish), there is no `gmon.out` ?
If I in the `submission.sh` I ask the job to run only for a duration of 3 minutes, and the job goes through the 3 minutes fine (even if the .f code does not reach its end), the `gmon.out` appears.

Is there an explanation for this?

I am compiling with `ifort` and I include the flag `-pg`.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably something like SIGTERM vs SIGKILL. Look up what the scancel actually does.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, thank you.  it seems that both SLURM's ``scancel`` and a normal end-time job-finish are sending ``SIGTERM``. both of them, after 30 seconds of this, send a ``SIGKILL`. the ``scancel`` command firstly issues a ``SIGCONT`` signal. it seems the normal finishing of the job does not firstly issue this ``SIGCONT``.